# Handling browser zoom in sites that mix canvas/webgl and html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a website which mixes html and WebGL/canvas. We're using WebGL/canvas to draw a graph with many elements, which proved to be too slow if drawn using html or svg.

The problem is that not our whole page is made in WebGL/canvas. The browser remembers the zoom from the html part of the website where zooming is fine, and then applies it to the part which uses WebGL, making the raster graph there blurry and too large for the window.

This is a major setback and a huge blow to the user experience. The worst part is that the browser won't even let me READ the zoom value so that I could AT LEAST notify the user about the issue, or even adjust the drawing based on the zoom.

Has anyone else run into this problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Would it be detrimental to UX if you completely disable zoom capabilities with an HTML header `meta` attribute?

Comment: Here's what we use to disable user zoom `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`, and obviously the `user-scalable=no` is the part that would disable it for you

Comment: Thank you. That would be fine as far as I'm concerned, however this doesn't seem to work on desktop browsers, but only on mobile.

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` is updated on desktop zoom, so you can use it to set the size of your canvas accordingly, and unscale it with css.

Comment: Hm, how come I couldn't find this? Everywhere I looked it said It wasn't possible to find out if the browser is zoomed. Even the library detect-zoom said it didn't work anymore. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you cannot know if it has been zoomed in before page load, different devices have different default values, but you can know it after page load.